# Attach image in S3 bucket to send with SendGrid

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sendgrid

I am writing an iOS app in *Swift* 2.2 using *Xcode* 7.3.1. Then, for backend services I am using *AWS Mobilehub* (*S3* and *Lambda*)

What the app should do: Take a screenshot, send it to an *AWS S3* bucket, send the screenshot through *SendGrid* by using an *AWS Lambda* function trigger.

My problem: I can't seem to attach the damn image in the S3 bucket to the email. Locally it works fine, but when uploaded to Lambda is throws the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...'

Using the following code:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

console.log('Loading function');

let aws = require('aws-sdk');
let s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));

    var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;

    let from_email = new helper.Email("from@gmail.com");
    let to_email = new helper.Email("to@gmail.com");
    let subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid Node.js Library";
    let content = new helper.Content("text/plain", "Email content");

    let mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);


    var bse64 = base64_encode(INeedThisFrigginPath);

    let attachment = new helper.Attachment();
    attachment.setContent(bse64);
    attachment.setType("image/png");
    attachment.setFilename(key);
    attachment.setDisposition("attachment");
    mail.addAttachment(attachment);

    var sg = require('sendgrid')('SG.sengridkey');

    var requestBody = mail.toJSON();
    var emptyRequest = require('sendgrid-rest').request;
    var requestPost = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emptyRequest));
    requestPost.method = 'POST';
    requestPost.path = '/v3/mail/send';
    requestPost.body = requestBody;
    sg.API(requestPost, 
            function (error, response) 
            {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                console.log(response.body);
                console.log(response.headers);
            }
    );
};

// function to encode file data to base64 encoded string
function base64_encode(file) 
{
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

Specifically this line:

```
var bse64 = base64_encode(INeedThisFrigginPath);
```

It's quite obvious what the problem is, so what I need to know is, what is **the correct path to my image**.

I have tried using the key value, and the image link:

> https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/public/test0.png

No luck.

It would be great if anyone can help me by supplying code, a tutorial or just general pointers to boost me into the right direction. Maybe using *AWS S3, AWS Lambda* and *SendGrid* isn't necessarily the best technologies to use here?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to build a path to that file and then you are trying to open it as a local file. The file isn't local, it's on S3, so you can't do that. You have two options:

- Download the file from S3 to Lambda first (into the /tmp directory) and then refer to the local path when you open the file.
- Open a ReadStream to the file using the AWS S3 SDK.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is this because Lambda functions run on a EC2 instance?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with that specifically. You just aren't ever going to be able to open a `file` to a remote S3 object from EC2 or Lambda or anywhere else. You have to either download the file from S3 first, or use the S3 SDK to open a stream.

Comment: Is the following line of code sending me in the right direction: `s3.download_file(bucket, key, '/tmp/img.png')`

Comment: That would download the file to the `/tmp` directory. Then you could pass that path to your `base64_encode` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, precisely what I needed